# How to move a column down one without deleting a row in R

Tags: r

I have data in 1 column which is off by 1 (the data needs to shift down by 1), all other columns are correct though. Currently I am moving the column down one using:

`df <- na.omit(transform(df,  region = c(NA, region[-nrow(df)])))`

However this seems to be removing the entire top row from my dataset (when I search for the gene in the first row after this line of code I cannot find it in the data) - is this what is happening in this line of code and is there a way to specify to not remove the top row when shifting down but place NA or 0 instead in the columns new top cell for that first row of data?

For example my data looks like this (the region column data is wrong and needs to shift down by 1):

```
Gene     Distance   Region
ACE          1       region1
BRCA         2       region2
NOTCH3       3       region2
EGFR         4       region2
P53          5       region3
```

I want my data output to be this:

```
Gene     Distance   Region
ACE          1       region1
BRCA         2       region1
NOTCH3       3       region2
EGFR         4       region2
P53          5       region2
```

My output with the code above currently looks like this:

```
Gene     Distance   Region
BRCA         2       region1
NOTCH3       3       region2
EGFR         4       region2
P53          5       region2
```

It wouldn't matter to me if the ACE region was just NA or 0, if possible, but I am not sure how to specify that.

Comment: Your first row disappears because your code sets the first `region` to `NA` then calls `na.omit` which removes rows containing `NA`s. On principle, you have the right idea, just remove your `na.omit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lag()` function from `dplyr` and set its defualt value appropriately:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Region = lag(Region, 
                      # if missing, as in first row, defaults to the first 
                      # value of df$region.
                      default = first(Region)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to shift `Region` column by 1 row, in base R you can do

```
df$Region[2:nrow(df)] <- df$Region[1:(nrow(df) - 1)]

df
#    Gene Distance  Region
#1    ACE        1 region1
#2   BRCA        2 region1
#3 NOTCH3        3 region2
#4   EGFR        4 region2
#5    P53        5 region2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("ACE", 
"BRCA", "EGFR", "NOTCH3", "P53"), class = "factor"), Distance = 1:5, 
Region = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("region1", 
"region2", "region3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `shift()` from `data.table`:

```
df$Region <- data.table::shift(df$Region, fill = df$Region[1])

    Gene Distance  Region
1    ACE        1 region1
2   BRCA        2 region1
3 NOTCH3        3 region2
4   EGFR        4 region2
5    P53        5 region2
```

Answer (score 0):

Unselect the first with `[-1]` and the last with `[-nrow(df)]` to shift by one.

```
df$Region[-1]  <- df$Region[-nrow(df)]
```